# No sound on Debian VM

Tags: debian, audio

I installed Debian+XFCE using VMware and [this YouTube video](http://youtu.be/VDVDZLEpKrw).

Everything runs OK, but I have no sound in the VM. What's wrong?

Comment: What host OS are you running VMware on? What are the related sound settings in VMware? What virtual sound card is presented in Debian? Did you check mixer settings e.g. using `alsamixer`?

Comment: @gertvdijk I am running VMware Workstation on Win7 64bit.
Related sound settings in VMware: "Use default host sound card"
Virtual sound card presented in debian: ENS1371 - Ensoniq AudioPCI
alsamixer's output is that everything is 100%

Comment: Also unmuted? What are you doing to produce the sound output in the VM? Did you try `speaker-test` for example?

Comment: How to check if it is muted or not?

And I try to play a youtube video and a mp3 file using VLC

Comment: On the bottom of the individual channels in the mixer there's either "`OO`" or "`MM`". O = open, M = muted. Toggle with keyboard "M".

Comment: Can't believe this was the problem...

Thanks from a debian noob :)

Answer (score 5):

<sup>Already verified solution from the comments, so posting as an answer.</sup>

Check for muted channels in the `alsamixer`. Muted channels are indicated with an `MM` state at the bottom of the vertical slider. Unmute it by selecting the right one using the arrow keys, then pressing <kbd>M</kbd> to toggle mute/unmute. Focus on Master and PCM. Unmute and turn them up until you hear sound from your source.